# Using Select Distinct and editing the output in the second column

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a list of unique names drawn from another table.

I was wondering if I could at the same time have an output that removes the special characters from those distinct values into another column using the same SQL query?

This is because I'll subsequently have to use these names as Table names and some of them have naming issues such as being too long or containing special characters.

I do have a `Function()` that returns a filtered string in the vba codes but not sure how to incorporate it into the SQL query.

This is the query I am using now:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO [ClientNameList] (ClientName) SELECT DISTINCT TempName.[ClientName] FROM TempName"
```

Output:

```
Table Name: ClientNameList
ID  ClientName  TableName
1   Cat.        Cat
2   Dog!        Dog
3   MooMoo?     MooMoo
```

Comment: Will there always be only the one special character located at the end? Use Left and Len functions: `Left(ClientName, Len(ClientName)-1)`. Why would you have a table for each ClientName?

Comment: Nope, there are special characters in the strings as well. Mostly company names so stuff like "Bla Bla Pte. Ltd.", "Jim's Bakery" or "Ace @ the Mall" are quite common.

Comment: So you want to end up with "JimsBakery" and "AcetheMall"? There is no intrinsic function to accomplish this. Create VBA custom function. Special characters can be used in naming convention, just not advised. Didn't answer other question. Why on Earth would you have a table for each client?

Comment: Ah my apologies. I've got the consumption data for individual clients stored in the individual tables. So this table with all the names kind of acts like a mapping table where knowing the client name directs user to the corresponding table. And yep, what  I suspected as well. I'll loop through the code then. Thanks!

Comment: I still don't understand why there is a table for each client.

Comment: You.....actually asked a very good question. My raw data comes in 3 major components. Client name, date and expenditure split hourly. I think it's neater to just split it by client name so each table only reflects 2 components.

Comment: Neater? And every time you get a new client you have to create a new table? This is actually poor relational db design. A functional db should rarely need design modification. Should be one table with another field for Client (really should be ID and not name). Also, at some point you are going to encounter a need to have all this data in one dataset and will have to resort to UNION query to accomplish. Easier to separate data by filtering than to merge.

Comment: You have a point here. Didn't think that far ahead. Just started building this db a week ago, still lots to learn. I'll try building a new one using your advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use/modify this function:

```
' Returns a cleaned and truncated string suitable as a code module name.
'
' 2017-03-06. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function TrimModuleCodeName( _
    ByVal Name As String) _
    As String

    CleanModuleCodeName Name

    TrimModuleCodeName = Name

End Function
```

which uses this function:

```
' Replaces characters in CodeName that are not allowed in a module codename.
' Truncates length of CodeName to MaxModuleCodeNameLength.
' Returns the cleaned name by reference.
'
' 2017-03-06. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Sub CleanModuleCodeName(ByRef CodeName As String)

    ' Maximum length of a module codename in Excel.
    Const MaxModuleCodeNameLength   As Long = 31
    ' String containing all not allowed characters.
    Const InvalidCharacters         As String = "\/,;.:*?'`""<>|()[]{} @#$%&=+-~^"
    ' String containing all not allowed leading characters.
    Const InvalidLeadCharacters     As String = "_0123456789"

    ' Character to replace not allowed characters.
    Const ReplaceCharacter          As String * 1 = "_"
    ' Character to replace not allowed characters.
    Const ReplaceLeadCharacter      As String * 1 = "M"

    Dim Length          As Integer
    Dim Position        As Integer
    Dim Character       As String
    Dim TrimmedCodeName As String

    ' Strip doubled spaces.
    While InStr(CodeName, Space(2)) > 0
        CodeName = Replace(CodeName, Space(2), Space(1))
    Wend
    ' Strip leading and trailing spaces and limit length of codename.
    TrimmedCodeName = Left(Trim(CodeName), MaxModuleCodeNameLength)
    Length = Len(TrimmedCodeName)
    ' Replace invalid characters.
    For Position = 1 To Length Step 1
        Character = Mid(TrimmedCodeName, Position, 1)
        If InStr(InvalidCharacters, Character) > 0 Then
            Mid(TrimmedCodeName, Position) = ReplaceCharacter
        End If
    Next
    ' Replace a leading invalid character:
    Character = Left(TrimmedCodeName, 1)
    If InStr(InvalidLeadCharacters, Character) > 0 Then
        Mid(TrimmedCodeName, 1) = ReplaceLeadCharacter
    End If

    ' Return cleaned code name.
    CodeName = TrimmedCodeName

End Sub
```

Then:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO [ClientNameList] (ClientName) SELECT DISTINCT TrimModuleCodeName(TempName.[ClientName]) FROM TempName"
```